# compilation error collection was modified

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting an error like

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute while
>   executing my code.

My requirement is as follows 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J48pV.png) 
enter any text in textbox and select the radio button and the text will be added as an item in the list box.If the text U're entering is already present in the text box then simply don't allow

code-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQW26.png)

here is my code-

```
            foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (li.Text.ToUpper() != TextBox1.Text.ToUpper())
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
                    Label2.Text = "<b style='color:green'> item updated in list box </b>";
                }
                else
                {
                    Label2.Text = "<b style='color:red'> access denied </b>";
                }
            }
```

I'm getting an error in foreach loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, you cann't modify the variable used for iterating inside of foreach. Simply use the for-loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListItem li = ListBox1.Items[i];
    if (li.Text.ToUpper() != TextBox1.Text.ToUpper())
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text); Label2.Text = "<b style='color:green'> item updated in list box </b>";
    }
    else { Label2.Text = "<b style='color:red'> access denied </b>"; }
}
```

P.S.
If you want to go only through existing items and not added inside of the loop, the you should save the current `Count`of Items in variable:

```
var itemCount = ListBox1.Items.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount ; i++)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Buddy you saved me .. Thanx a ton man. almost i banged my head for this shit :p

Answer (score 0):

Just do this for the loop instead:

```
foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items.ToList())
```

Comment: the statement- ListBox1.Items.ToList() is showing an error .. The problem is solved actually. Simply I was modifying variables inside foreach loop which is not allowed.. Thank You for ur comment :)

Comment: If it's showing an error, it's because you need to add `using System.Linq`.